# How can I set my strap to communicate with my HTTPS FrontEnd?

Tags: strapi

I have an Angular FrontEnd that needs the ZXing package for the camera application. This requires my front end to be hosted on the server over HTTPS. Now I have the problem: how can I let my HTTPS FrontEnd communicate with my HTTP Strapi Backend?

Thanks in advance!
Please see Attachment!

[image]

Comment: Serve the backend with https, that's the only way.

Comment: @Christian Hello, thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately I have little experience with servers. I found this article:
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/getting-started/troubleshooting.html#frequently-asked-questions
I still haven't understood correctly. Do I also have to set up a proxy for this?
In Angular I just added CRT and KEY. Can I do the same with Strapi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a localhost server and set up a tunnel to that (so it is available as an https website). Follow the [quick start here](https://ngrok.com/)  to install ngrok on your machine then execute the following

```
# terminal session 1
yarn start (or strapi start)
```

```
# terminal session 2
ngrok http 1337
```

You'll then be provided with a domain from which you can access your localhost strapi. For example - https://8fac9bd9.ngrok.io.

When you're ready, you can deploy strapi to a [variety of services](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/getting-started/deployment.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! Incidentally, I have now also solved the problem with NginX. :)

Answer (score 0):

To provide a slightly updated answer:

```
// server.ts
export default ({ env }) => ({
  // other defaults
  url: env('SERVER_URL', 'http://localhost:1337'),
});
```

This uses an env config if available, or defaults to the normal one. Then just add the config to your env.

```bash
// .env
SERVER_URL=https://{your ngrok url}
```